# Prerendering React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have an application using React, React Router, Redux and Webpack for bundling, basically the problem is the client said that the SEO is bad because the content or the way on React render the app, because if you go to see the source is not there, I understand that the Googlebot can crawl an SPA, I checked the Fetch as Google and the pages are rendering good, but the client feels that is is the problem.
I tested with react-snapshot, prerender-spa-plugin, static-site-generator-webpack-plugin, and also Next but anyone of these does not work for me. I want to know if exists a way to resolve this without changing the project structure or at least reasons or an explanation to not do this. Thanks

Comment: React has a serverside rendering function with react-dom-server. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Comment: Worth reading : [Netflix Techblog on how to optimize react](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/crafting-a-high-performance-tv-user-interface-using-react-3350e5a6ad3b), and [Netflix functions without React](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/netflix-and-react/)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can do this with React's [server-side rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) feature.

For each function, in the Node.js server that responds to the request for the page:

1. `require(..)` your root component.
2. `require(..)` your redux store
3. Call actions to move the store to the state the page needs - including fetching any data that it needs
4. Pass the store to your root component and call [`ReactDOMServer.renderToString`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) on it. Note react router has [special handling](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md) for server-side rendering so read that.
5. Server that HTML to the user under the root element in your markup.
6. Call [`ReactDOM.hydrate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate) on it with your store on the client side.

Alternatively if your code has `window.x` all around and can't run in Node.js - you can do something else just for SEO:

1. Detect whether or not a user is Googlebot - with [spider-detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spider-detector) for example.
2. If it is, use [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to get the [content](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.5.0/docs/api.md#pagecontent) of the HTML page
3. Serve that content to the spider instead - since it will wait for AJAX calls to finish and the state will be solid. Since this is expensive you want to cache pages for at least a few minutes.

Note that regular users still get the regular React site as they are not detected as crawlers.

Comment: How can I use the just for SEO thing? Thank you for the answer

Comment: @AlejandroMata here's a Google tutorial on how to do this for SEO with puppeteer which I recommend - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/articles/ssr .

Comment: In addition to this, you can use prender-spa-plugin to make content ready dom https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Basically agree with the idea upstairs (Benjamin Gruenbaum)
The difference is that I use puppeteer directly.

1. When the project is packaged, start a headless puppeteer,The headless puppeteer will not send any ajax, it can get a skeleton diagram .
2. get the static content of the page, and replace your html.